# Python Multiplication Program Game, Try again option

Tags: python, multiplication

I was trying to do a multiplication program where after one wrong answer, it will get the chance to try again one more time.

that is my code:

```
from random import randint

wrong_answers = 0

for turn in range(100):

    # Choose two random integers for the question to the player
    factor_1 = randint(2,12)
    factor_2 = randint(2,12)

    # Precompute the correct answer to be able to check the player's answer
    correct_answer = factor_1*factor_2

    # As the question and get the player's response
    question = 'What is ' + str(factor_1) + ' times ' + str(factor_2) + ' times ' + '?'
    answer_string = raw_input(question)

    #Convert the player's response to a number (raw_input yields a string)
    answer_int = int(answer_string)

    # See if the player's answer is correct or not, and proceed accordingly
    if (answer_int == correct_answer):
        print 'Correct!'
    else:
        print 'Wrong! Try Again!'
        raw_input(question)
        answer_int = int(answer_string)
    if raw_input() == correct_answer:
            print 'Correct'
    else:
            wrong_answers = wrong_answers + 1
    if wrong_answers == 2:
            print 'Game Over Thanks for playing!!!'
            exit()
```

The problem is when ask the question again, it does not compute the right answer.. it will ignore it and count as wrong answer. After the second wrong answer the program ends.

Is there any way to make the question again, count the right answer and if the person puts the wrong answer again count as error and the program continues?

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary re-ask for the answer. In fact, you shouldn't do it because at this point the program hasn't processed the answer yet. I would increment the *wrong_answers* variable in the first "else", so the code would look like this:

```
# See if the player's answer is correct or not, and proceed accordingly
if (answer_int == correct_answer):
    print 'Correct!'
else:
    if wrong_answers < 1:
        print 'Wrong! Try Again!'
    else:
        print 'Wrong!'
    wrong_answers = wrong_answers + 1
```

Note that the output will be "Wrong! Try Again!" when the answer doesn't produce a game over. If the game has finished it will be "Wrong! Game Over Thanks for playing!!!".

I leave here the demo: https://repl.it/ByyD/0.

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

When you re-ask for the answer, you don't assign what the user entered to `answer_string`, so it uses the original value to compute `answer_int`.  But I guess that doesn't matter, since you use `raw_input()` instead of `answer_int` to see if the entry was correct.

Comment: I modified this part, i think now it works:

else:
        print 'Wrong! Try Again!'
        answer_string = raw_input()
        answer_int = int(answer_string)
    if answer_int == correct_answer:
            print 'Correct'i modified this part: